# Apple Enterprise app - what is the best way to make new Provisioning Profile available to users

Tags: ios, xcode

We have an iPad Enterprise app in use at our company by about 20 users.

The Distribution certificate does not expire until January 2019. But the Distribution Provisioning Profile expires in January 2017.

Obviously we could rebuild the .ipa with a new provisioning profile and get the users to re-download and install the new version of the app.

However, because the full app is about 3GB in size, I would prefer to just send out or otherwise make available, only the new distribution provisioning profile.

We don't use an MDM solution.

If we sent out the new DPP by email, would the user just be able to double click it and have it install to the app automatically?

Thanks

Lisa